# Game Maker Networking

Tags: networking, game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

Recently, I started playing around with Game Maker to make a very simple game with the ability to play online (multiplayer). I made a very simple client & server. I can send data from the server to the client, but I can't send the data from the client to the server.

Client: (Create event)

```
client_socket = network_create_socket(network_socket_tcp);
var server = network_connect(client_socket, "127.0.0.1", 5200);
if(server < 0) show_message("Could not connect! Try turning on the server?");
else{ //Send string
    var t_buffer = buffer_create(256, buffer_grow, 1);
    buffer_seek(t_buffer, buffer_seek_start, 0);
    buffer_write(t_buffer , buffer_string, "Hello");
    network_send_packet(client_socket, t_buffer, buffer_tell(t_buffer));
    buffer_delete(t_buffer);
}
```

Server: (Create event)

```
server_socket = network_create_server(network_socket_tcp, 5200, 5);
```

(Async Network event)

```
var n_id = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "id");
if(n_id == server_socket){
    var t = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "type");
    socketlist = ds_list_create();
    if(t == network_type_connect){
        var sock = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "socket");
        ds_list_add(socketlist, sock);
    }
    if(t == network_type_data){
        var t_buffer = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "buffer"); 
        var cmd_type = buffer_read(t_buffer, buffer_string);
        show_message(cmd_type);
    }
    //show_message("Something happened!");
}
```

For some reason, the async network event in the server is never triggered when the client sends data. The message `Something happened!` only comes up when the client either connects or disconnects, but not when data is sent. Using almost the exact same code, I can send from the server, but not vice versa. Is this a problem with the code or just a server/client limitation?

Answer (score 2):

This is the server side code:

```
var n_id = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "id");
if(n_id == server_socket){
    var t = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "type");
    socketlist = ds_list_create();
    if(t == network_type_connect){
        sock = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "socket");
        ds_list_add(socketlist, sock);
    }
}

if(n_id == sock) {
    var t_buffer = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "buffer"); 
    var cmd_type = buffer_read(t_buffer, buffer_string);
    show_message(cmd_type);
}
```

You have to use the socket id when a message is arriving. The `network_type_data` will never be triggered.

Also, you have to declare the `sock` variable in the server's create event with a negative number (like noone (-4)).